# Call url and send JSONObject with HttpGet

Tags: java, web-services, maven, httpclient, http-get

I'm currently working on a Java application project. It's an existing application and I was asked to modify it. They say that I have to make a web service that calls another app (calls is url) then pass a data to it from the ini file of the application I'm modifying. I'm just new with this kind of stuff, I really home someone can help me. So here's the code that writes the ini file:

```
               common.writeIniFileIdentify("PV-ID", PVIDNo);
               common.writeIniFileIdentify("PALMUS-ID", SerialNo);
```

And I converted it to strings:

```
               Properties p = new Properties();
               p.load(new FileInputStream("C:/PALMUS-PV/PVInfo.ini"));
               String pvid = p.getProperty("PV-ID");
               String palmusid = p.getProperty("PALMUS-ID");
               System.out.println(pvid);
               System.out.println(palmusid);

               this.sendPVDetails(pvid, palmusid); //this will pass the data to sendPVDetails method
```

And this is the HttpGet that I use (just saw this on the internet):

```
public void sendPVDetails(String pvid, String palmusid) {
      try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(
                "https://url.of.the.another.application");

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("PV-ID", pvid);
        jsonObject.put("PALMUS-ID", palmusid);

        getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
               + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                         new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }           

        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

      } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }
```

I'm a bit confused on how the HttpGet works cause it's my first time seeing this kind of codes and java is also new for me. they say that I have to use 'return ResponseEntity' but it's just for controller and the method I'm using is not a controller. I really hope someone can guide me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP GET method is use for retrieve content from a given URI. Since we are only suppose to call GET on a URI there won't be any content involved. In order to post (send) some content to a given URI you need to use HTTP POST. You can use [HttpPost](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) in order to fulfill your requirement.[Here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/) Is a good example of using http client library.